# How to enable a host to reply to multicast ping

Tags: linux, networking, ping, tcpdump, multicast

I'm experimenting with `multicast` traffic within my wireless network and tried to ping some pre-defined multicast address:

```
$ ping 224.0.0.251
```

The `ip` address of the ping machine is `192.168.0.11`. So I ran `tcpdump` on another `Linux` machine within the same `LAN` and noticed the following:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -vv -n -i eth0 icmp
05:33:31.567847 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 23235, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.0.11 > 224.0.0.251: ICMP echo request, id 23235, seq 1, length 64
06:33:32.570106 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 42255, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.0.11 > 224.0.0.251: ICMP echo request, id 42255, seq 2, length 64
```

As can be seen the `ICMP` packets are received on that particular member of the multicast group, but the `ICMP` echo reply is not sent back. Why? Is it possible to configure it to be sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=0
```